# Надо ли создавать интерфейсы для публичных методов, служащих только для тестирования?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты

У меня есть геттеры и сеттеры, которые используются только для юнит-тестов.
Надо ли их оформлять в интерфейсах или можно просто в тестах обращаться не через интерфейс, а напрямую?

Comment: Как по мне, весьма странно изменять контракт интерфейса из-за тестов. Если в самой программе вам геттеры и сеттеры точно не нужны, то их не должно быть ни в интерфейсе, ни в тестах.

Comment: геттеров и сеттеров должно быть почти 0 (исключение "глупые" объекты - DTO, VO). добавлять их ради тестирования не рекомендуется. тестируйте поведение объектов, а не состояние.

Comment: >>тестируйте поведение объектов, а не состояние<<< поведение приводит к изменению состояния вот я и проверяю состояние как результат поведения, тем самым проверяя правильность поведения. Не понял вас, извините не могли бы чуть подробнее объяснить? >>>"глупые" объекты - DTO, VO<<< а как расшифровываются аббревиатуры DTO и VO?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример кода (тестируемого и самого теста).

Comment: Если ваш класс знает, что его кто-то юнит-тестирует - вы что-то делаете не так

Comment: Да можно вообще интерфейсы не использовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему у вас не верный подход к юнит-тестированию. Как сказал Mikhail Vaysman в своем комментарии:

> тестируйте поведение объектов, а не состояние

Ваш класс служит какой-то цели и имеет набор публичных методов, а значит и нужно тестировать именно поведение этих методов, а не внутреннюю реализацию класса. По большому счету, человек пишущий тесты может вообще не знать о том как реализован класс, ему важно только иметь описание публичных членов класса и оперировать ими при написании теста.

Для примера представим, что у вас есть самописный класс дублирующий `StringBuilder`. Допустим внутри класса есть приватное поле типа `char[]` хранящее введенную строку посимвольно.

Вы хотите протестировать метод `void append(String s)`, который должен добавить в конец хранимой на текущей момент строки переданную в качестве аргумента метода строку. Суть тестирования в данном случае в том, что объект класса при вызове метода `toString()` должен вернуть строку того, что было в объекте плюс то, что вы добавили тестируемым методом `append`. То есть правильный тест должен оперировать публичными методами класса.

Допустим вы пошли другим путем и каким-то образом достучались до приватных членов класса через рефлексию или еще как-нибудь. Теперь вы тестируете метод `append` анализируя как изменяется внутреннее хранилище объекта. С виду ничего не изменилось. Если кто-то полез в реализацию метода `append` и метод стал работать неверно, то ваш тест завалится, как вам и требуется. Но допустим вы сами или кто-то еще решил изменить реализацию внутреннего хранилища строки. Может он переименовал поле, может теперь таких полей несколько, а может он вообще перенес хранилище в облако и теперь оно хранится где-то на других серверах. Не важно. Важно то, что при этом метод `toString` после вызова `append` возвращает именно то, что ожидается. Но при этом ваш тест завалится. То есть все работает правильно, а тест завалился! Поэтому, при написании теста, нужно оперировать только публичными методами.